# Sendgrid Node.js Error: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I'm using Sendgrid to send a transactional Email with Firebase Cloud Functions using Nodejs.

```
const attachment = file.createReadStream();

const msg = {
  to: email,
  from: "test@test.com",
  subject: "print order",
  templateId: "templateid",
  dynamic_template_data: {
    dashboardurl: `/order#${orderId}`,
    downloadurl: orderData.downloadurl
  },
  attachments: [{
    content: attachment,
    filename: "order.pdf",
    type: "application/pdf",
    disposition: "attachment"
  }]
};
await sgMail.send(msg);
```

The Email won't send, because of the following bug:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

**Solution for Firebase Storage**

```
const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), "tmp.pdf");
await file.download({ destination: tempFilePath });
const attachment = fs.readFileSync(tempFilePath, { encoding: "base64"   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [doc](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/use-cases/attachments.md):

For content you send base64 encoded version of the file.

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'recipient@example.org',
  from: 'sender@example.org',
  subject: 'Hello attachment',
  html: '<p>Here’s an attachment for you!</p>',
  attachments: [
    {
      content: 'Some base 64 encoded attachment content',
      filename: 'some-attachment.txt',
      type: 'plain/text',
      disposition: 'attachment',
      contentId: 'mytext'
    },
  ],
};
```

So in your case below conversion would suffice:

```
const attachment = fs.readFileSync('filepath', { encoding: 'base64' });
```

Comment: I get following error using the conversion: `TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer`

Comment: `file` is not file object, `file` here is path of the file.